# get <!DOCTYPE> of xml file in php using xml reader

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

Here is Sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Catalog SYSTEM "http://store.yahoo.com/doc/dtd/Catalog.dtd">
<Catalog Store`enter code here`ID="yhst-69328165909994" StoreName="Inmod Modern Furniture" PublishTimestamp="1517733517">
  <Table ID="main-table-for-download">
    <TableField ID="name" Type="text"/>
    <TableField ID="sale-price" Type="numbers"/>
    <TableField ID="path" Type="text"/>
    <TableField ID="taxable" Type="yes-no"/>
    <TableField ID="ship-weight" Type="numbers"/>
    <TableField ID="price" Type="numbers"/>
    <TableField ID="orderable" Type="orderable"/>
    <TableField ID="code" Type="text"/>
  </Table>
```

I just want to get this element

after reading that XML file.I need to check if that XML file contains yahoo feed or not?

you can suggest any better option for that too.

**My Attempt :**

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->xml($myxmlfilecontent);
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        while ($reader->read()) {
            if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
                //array_push($nodeList, $reader->localName);
                if (stripos($xml, 'yahoo') !== false) {
                    echo 'yahoo read';die
                }else{
                    echo 'not yahoo read';die 
                }                   
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Basically in this example i am searching yahoo in whole file,
i don't want to search in whole file i just want to get doc type element and search on that string.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the node type as being a `DOC_TYPE` node and then fetch the xml for that node using `readOuterXml()`...

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->xml($myxmlfilecontent);
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::DOC_TYPE) {
        echo $reader->readOuterXml();
    }
}
```

This outputs -

```
<!DOCTYPE Catalog SYSTEM "http://store.yahoo.com/doc/dtd/Catalog.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of XMLReader, you could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and get the [systemId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumenttype.php#domdocumenttype.props.systemid):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($myxmlfilecontent);
$systemId = $doc->doctype->systemId;
if (stripos($systemId, 'yahoo') !== false) {
    echo "yahoo read";
} else {
    echo "not yahoo read";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/rErVX)